# Query AncestryOf with Laravel-nestedset in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using [Laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) and am having a hard time querying the `ancestrosOf` my category model.

This is what I am trying to do:

**Works**

http://carnival-experts.test/categories (this gives me a list of all categories)

http://carnival-experts.test/categories/carnival-games (this gives me a list of all Carnival Games)

**Does Not Work**

http://carnival-experts.test/categories/carnival-games/large-scale-games (this shows me a list of Carnival Games and not the Large Scale Games category)

I am sure this is just my lack of understanding--any help appreciated.

**web.php**

```
...
Route::get('/', 'CategoryController@index')->name('categories');
Route::get('/{category}/{slug?}', 'CategoryController@show')->name('show');
...
```

**CategoryController.php**

```
...
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()

    {
        $categories = Category::get()->toTree();

        return view('categories.index', compact('categories'));
    }

    public function show(Category $category, $slug = null)
    {
        if (!is_null($slug)) {
            $categories = Category::ancestorsOf($category);
            return view('categories.show_subcategory', compact('categories', 'category', 'slug'));
        } else {
            return view('categories.show', compact('category'));
        }

    }

}
```

**show_category.blade.php**

```
...
@foreach($category['children']->chunk(3) as $chunk)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($chunk as $category)
            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 2rem">
                <div class="feature-box center media-box fbox-bg">
                    <div class="fbox-media">
                        <a href="/categories/{{$category->slug}}">
                            <img class="image_fade"
                                 src="https://*****.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/{{ $category->photo }}"
                                 alt="Featured Box Image"
                                 style="opacity: 1;"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fbox-desc">
                        <h3>{{$category->name}}</h3>
                        <span><a href="/categories/{{$category->slug}}">Learn More</a></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            Products
            @if(count($category->products) > 0)
                @foreach($category->products as $product)
                    {{$product->title}}
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
...
```

Comment: How does the name 'carnival-games' get translated to a `$category` model when the `show()` function is called? Also, can you show some sample data?